# Zabbix upgrade to 4.0.2

Tags: zabbix

*Greetings!*

I do not know how to upgrade from Zabbix 4.0.1 to Zabbix 4.0.2
What I'm trying to do:

```
rm -Rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zabbix.list
wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/4.0/debian/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_4.0-2+stretch_all.deb
dpkg -i zabbix-release_4.0-2+stretch_all.deb
apt-get update
apt-get install --only-upgrade zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-frontend-php zabbix-agent
```

It says that there is no new version. And I'm still on 4.0.1.
Any guess why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it!
In some reason there was no zabbix.list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

What I've did - add next line to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/4.0/debian stretch main
```

after i did `apt-get update` and `apt-get install --only-upgrade zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-frontend-php zabbix-agent`
That's all!